# Access y VB.NET

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ms-access-2010

Mi problema es que defino una consulta con parámetros en **MS ACCESS** y no la veo en los orígenes de datos en **Visual Studio 2015**.

La consulta es:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT * 
       FROM Ingresos,IngresosLin,PuenteContab 
       WHERE Ingresos.NroRecIng = IngresosLin.NroRecIng 
             And CtaDeuIng=Ctactb 
             And Ingresos.NroRecIng=?
     ) AS Rec, PuenteContab
WHERE MovIng = PuenteContab.Mvto;
```

Funciona correcto en **Access**. Pero no la veo en **Visual Studio** ya que la configura como función y no tengo acceso a ella para los reportes.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: o sea lo defines como view en ms access ? porque si es asi en el codigo deberias realizar un SELECT a esa view para obtener los registros. Dond es que no lo visualizas? ademas que reporte estas usando?

Comment: Leandro, gracias por tu interes, lo que dices es correcto, lo defino en Access como una consulta, pero en el origen de datos de Visual Studio (2015) no lo veo y uso ReportViewer como manejador de reportes, hace unos años Crystal Report me dió muchos problemas y lo descarté

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución es que crees la misma consulta sin parámetros y la filtres en el origen de datos del reporte.

Espero haberte ayudado, Saludos

Comment: Gracias, fue lo que hice...